# How can I use sudo when I logged in with a SSH key in PuTTY?

Tags: debian, sudo

I know the title probably doesn't even make sense, but anyway. I downloaded PuTTY and set it up, and followed [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-ssh-keys-authentication-with-putty-and-linux-server-in-5-quick-steps) to set up SSH keys so I don't have to input a user or password when logging in with SSH. I noticed that when I made a new user I used the `--disabled-password` parameter, since I wouldn't be needing it... but now when I give the user sudo powers I can't proceed as it asks me for the user's password, and I don't have one.

What do I do?

Comment: ask for passwordless sudo

Comment: What you do depends on what you want to happen, which you didn't tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to configure sudo to don't ask password:
In the file `/etc/sudoers` you have some lines starting with username or groupname (groupnames start with a '%'). Choose the desired line and add the `NOPASSWD` option. Example:
`%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
This will allow every user belonging to the group named sudo to use sudo without password.
BEWARE: mistakes are easy !

For more informations, see `man sudoers`

You can edit `/etc/sudoers` by hand, but it is advised to use the `visudo` command (wich will lauch a text editor, and once you quit will check the file for correctness. If anything fail, the file remain untouched).

Answer (score 5):

Disable password authentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Restart sshd.

Then set a password for the user. As you created the user you have root access, so as root

```
passwd user
Changing password for user user.
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

This will then allow you to sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login as root and set the password?

Here's how you should have done it:

1. Generate SSH Key
2. Make sure you can login with ssh key
3. Make sure you can sudo to root
4. Disable passwordauthentication in sshd_conf
5. Disable root login in sshd_conf